# How to get order id in woocommerce restapi v3

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, rest

I tried to use Woo Commerce RestApi V3 and have problems getting data from orders I try with:

```
use Automattic\WooCommerce\Client;

$autoloader = dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/vendor/autoload.php';
if ( is_readable( $autoloader ) ) {
    require_once $autoloader;
}

$client = new Client(
    url, key, secret,
    [
        'wp_api'  => true,
        'version' => 'wc/v3',
    ]

$result = $client->get('orders', [
  'status' => 'completed',
  'filter[created_at_min]' => '2018-09-01',
  'filter[limit]' => 1500
]); 

$mysqli->query("BEGIN");

foreach($result as $orders){
    //dp($result);
    foreach($orders as $order){
...
```

So I get `$order` but I can not get order id and other data to variables as `$order_id`

I tried `$order_id = $order->id;` and `$order_id = $order['id'];` but it is not working. br>

I also tried with `get_id()` but gives fatal error

Comment: What does the output of print_r($order) look like in the inside foreach loop

Comment: It looks like:52598052598wc_order_NKjD1lyAQdmascheckout4.7.0completedEUR2021-01-21T11:04:002021-01-21T10:04:002021-01-21T11:04:092021-01-21T10:04:090.000.000.000.0017.4997.0017.4910193.77.185.25Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_6) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/14.0.1 Safari/605.1.15stdClass Object ( [first_name] => Ewa Neja [last_name] => Pipenbaher [company] => VATES, družba za prodajo vozil, poslovne storitve in spletno trgovino, d.o.o. [address_1] => Slomškova ulica 19 [address_2] => [city] => Slovenska Bistrica [state] => [postcode] => 2310

Comment: There doesn't appear to be an id being returned. Can you add the output to your original question by editing the question so it can be formatted more simply. 
Also try a var_dump($order); it will tell you if it's an object or an array

Comment: int(52598) int(0) string(5) "52598" string(22) "wc_order_NKjD1lyAQdmas" string(8) "checkout" string(5) "4.7.0" string(9) "completed" string(3) "EUR" string(19) "2021-01-21T11:04:00" string(19) "2021-01-21T10:04:00" string(19) "2021-01-21T11:04:09" string(19) "2021-01-21T10:04:09" string(4) "0.00" string(4) "0.00" string(4) "0.00" string(4) "0.00" string(5) "17.49" string(5) "97.00" string(5) "17.49" bool(true) int(0) string(13) "193.77.185.25" string(119) "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_6) string(0) "" object(stdClass)#13 (11) { ["first_name"]=> string(8) "Ewa Neja"

Comment: Order ID is 52598

Comment: Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 53665
            [parent_id] => 0
            [number] => 53665
            [order_key] => wc_order_DygTQ8e6Tlz0J
            [created_via] => checkout
            [version] => 4.8.0
            [status] => completed
            [currency] => EUR
            [date_created] => 2021-01-30T14:31:03
            [date_created_gmt] => 2021-01-30T14:31:03
            [date_modified] => 2021-01-30T14:31:06
            [date_modified_gmt] => 2021-01-30T14:31:06
            [discount_total] => 0.00

Comment: Can you please edit the question with these things you are adding so they can be formatted more neatly. Don't just keep adding comments. 
Perhaps you don't need to do 2 foreach loops. foreach ($result as $order) ?

Comment: Ok. Now i got order id. Iremoved scond for each and now is working.

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: Can you also help me with getting meta_data fields of order?

Comment: I need to get _billing_eu_vat_number field.

Comment: I got it with foreach($order->meta